# How to pass values of jQuery slider to onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery slider that has two handles that has values each and changes values when I move them. What i want to know is, is it possible to pass the values of those two handles to a single onclick event?

Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showAvailable(slidervalue1, slidervalue2)">Submit</a>
```

The slidervalue1 and slidervalue2 are the values from the slider and put in the showAvalailable event.

Here is the code for the showAvailable():

```
function showAvailable(firstValue, secondValue)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("availableShown").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","showavailable.php?startShift="+firstValue+"&endShift="+secondValue,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Is it possible? And if so, how do I pass it?
Any kind oh help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please show your `showAvailable`

Comment: You should see it now. I Edited my post.

Comment: so? what's the problem? inside the `slide` function you just need to change your variables values...

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how to get the variables values from the jQuery UI slider function. Im sorry im just a beginner. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply getting the slider current value:

```
$("#yourSliderID").slider("value");
```

http://jsbin.com/hewulaze/2/edit?js,console,output

```
$(function() { // DOM ready 

  // 
  var $sli1 = $('#slider1'),
      $sli2 = $('#slider2');

  $sli1.slider({
    max: 1000,
    value: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      console.log( "Slider1 : "+ ui.value );
    }
  });

  $sli2.slider({
    max: 10000,
    value: 5000,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      console.log( "Slider2 : "+ ui.value );
    }
  }); 


  function showAvailable(){         
     alert( $sli1.slider("value") ); // test current values.
     alert( $sli2.slider("value") );
  }

  $('#showAvail').click( showAvailable );  // Call function

});
```

Now that you hopefully understand why you see alert boxes with values in your browser let's see how to use those values.

your new function should look like:

```
function showAvailable(){

  var firstValue = $sli1.slider("value");
  var secondValue= $sli2.slider("value");

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
       document.getElementById("availableShown").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","showavailable.php?startShift="+firstValue+"&endShift="+secondValue,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: Im gonna accept your answer. But an alert just shows up that displays the values I submitted. But how do I pass those values to another php page just like in the codes the post? I want to pass those values to showavailable.php when I click the hyperlink with an onclick event.

Comment: Ok. Wow, I didn't know that was possible. Can you show me how please? Thank you very much though.

Comment: It makes sense. I know where the alert came from. I just didn't know you could pass those variables to php. Im really sorry I'm just a beginner. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.